# Передача данных в android

Tags: android, графика

имеется два класса. Нужно передать параметры из GraphicsDemo в Draw2D. Как я понимаю, intent.putExtra(,) используется при вызове новой активности startActivity(intent). Подскажите, как быть в этой ситуации.

public class GraphicsDemo extends Activity {

int a=2;

```
 @Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(new Draw2D(this));  
}}
```

.........................................................................................

public class Draw2D extends View{

int a1;

```
Paint paint = new Paint();    
public Draw2D(Context context) {
        super(context);
    } 
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);       
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    //рисование    
}}
```

Comment: А передать их через конструктор религия не позволяет? или отдельным методом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1. Через конструктор:

```
    setContentView(new Draw2D(this, a));
```

..................................................................

```
    public Draw2D(Context context, int a) {
        super(context);
        a1 = a;
    }
```

Вариант 2. Создайте экземпляр Вашего класса и обращайтесь к его полям, методам:

```
     Draw2D mDraw2D = new Draw2D(this); 
     mDraw2D.a1 = a;
     mDraw2D.setA1(a);
     setContentView(mDraw2D);
```